# python string aligning format

Tags: python

I have some strings in python that I want to aling with each other but can't seem to do it.

```
 a = ("adam, home, wednesday, 17th")
 b = ("Tiffany, office, monday, 9th")
```

I split them out by ","

I am wanting output of:

```
 adam         home     wednesday     17th
 tiffany      office   monday        9th
```

I am trying to use

```
 working_line =('{0} {1:<20} {2:<15} {3:<10}'.format(source,group,symbol,position))
```

this isn't working and I am a little confused...

Comment: your `a` and `b` variable definitions are not legal python.

Comment: @abarnert: The original post didn't have that sentence about using split, and furthermore didn't have ending "'s so it wasn't legal Python.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Ah, I see. SO says this post has no edits, which is a bit confusing if it actually has edits that address all of the comments…

Comment: @abarnert: There is a grace period of 5 minutes where one can edit one's own post without the edits showing up in the history.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Did he also change `working_line`? Because the current version seems to actually do exactly what he says he wants, and also what Martijn Pieters' answer suggests, so there's no clue what his actual problem is.

Comment: @abarnert: Yes (see his comment below "corrected, just a typing error"). This makes it very unclear: is there still a problem? (Incidentally, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9090/is-there-an-editing-grace-period-on-answers-after-they-have-been-posted) for more about the grace period).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you do something like this instead:

```
a = ['adam', 'home', 'wednesday', '17th']
b = ['Tiffany', 'office', 'monday', '9th']

for x in [a, b]:
    working_line = ' '.join(map(lambda s: s.ljust(10, ' '), x))
    print working_line
```

Here's the output:

```
adam       home       wednesday  17th      
Tiffany    office     monday     9th
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a colon in the `{3}` field definition:

```
working_line =('{0} {1:<20} {2:<15} {3:<10}'.format(source,group,symbol,position))
```

Comment: @AdamG.: so is there still a question?

Comment: @AdamG.: the code in my answer *works*. From your question post it is not clear what doesn't work for you.